# Image broken link

Tags: php, laravel

I will need your help as my image url appear to be broken in my browser which am sure i did everything correctly or so i think. I want to add an image to my update profile user acc below is how my code circle is structure. This  my user table schema

```
 *public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('role_id')->default(2);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
            $table->text('about')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }*
```

, this my setting controller that have the updateProfile method

```
*public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'image' => 'required|image',
        ]);
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $slug = str_slug($request->name);
        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::id());
        if (isset($image))
        {
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imageName = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists('profile'))
            {
             Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('profile');
            }
//            Delete old image form profile folder
            if (Storage::disk('public')->exists('profile/'.$user->image))
            {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete('profile/'.$user->image);
            }
            $profile = Image::make($image)->resize(500,500)->stream();
            Storage::disk('public')->put('profile/'.$imageName,$profile);
        } else {
            $imageName = $user->image;
        }
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->image = $imageName;
        $user->about = $request->about;
        $user->save();
        Toastr::success('Profile Successfully Updated :)','Success');
        return redirect()->back();*
```

, i  have use the php artisan storage:link and here is my view linking to my public/profile directory

```
 *<a class="avatar" href="{{ route('author.profile',$post->user->username) }}"><img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url('profile/'.$post->user->image) }}" alt="Profile Image"></a>*
```

. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is file uploaded in a folder?

Comment: Have you checked whether your profile directory have permissions to access the image on frontend if you are on live server ?

Comment: Madhusdan yes file is uploaded in folder. Rajender verma am developing locally and this my config/filesystem default setting  'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

Comment: Try `'/profile/'.$post->user->image`, notice the added slash. Have a look at the HTML source, does it show what you expected?

Comment: Let me try it will get back to you. I do appreciate your time.

Comment: It still doesn't work is it okay to set my 'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'), to local.

Comment: Can you dump Storage::get('profile/' . $post->user->image) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how i solve my own problem and thanks to everyone who try to assist me am grateful.

```
 *<a class="avatar" href="{{ route('author.profile',$post->user->username) }}"> 
               <img src="{{ asset('Storage/profile/'.$post->user->image) }}" alt="Profile Image"></a>*
```